# Select GeoTIFF from a database via GeoServer and OpenLayers3

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers, wms, sql

I'm almost a beginner at PostGIS and GeoServer so I hope you could help me with my question.

In my PostGIS database I have a lot of GeoTIFFs that I would like to display in a WebGIS via GeoServer and OpenLayers3.

Every hour a new GeoTIFF with temperature information is coming.

INCA-T2M_20160614T1300.tif

INCA-T2M_20160614T1400.tif

INCA-T2M_20160614T1500.tif etc.

I upload them via raster2pgsql into the database.
There they have the columns rid, rast and filename

Now I would like to build a query in the WebGIS where the user could type a date and time and the suitable GeoTIFF will be displayed. 
Therefore I have to build the correct WMS request with OpenLayers3 and send them to the GeoServer. 
But how does the correct WMS-request looks like and how the GeoServer will ask my database for the correct table?

After reading the GeoServer documentation maybe the creation of an [sql view with parameter](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html) could be the solution?

The examples here are dealing with the selection of a specific range of data from a fix table. But I don't know how do I have to build a query to ask for a specific table, not for a range of data in a fix table.

But maybe I'm on a wrong path... Do you have any idea?

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html - it's all built in except keeping rasters in postgis - use the disk instead much quicker.

Comment: is the XY extent the same for each raster, just time and temperature changing?  if so you consider a web coverage service (WCS) solution instead of a WMS.